# Windows Installation?

Tags: origen-sdk

Can someone tell me if Origen is supported on the Windows platform?

If it is, is there a guide for the installation process?

If not, are there any plans to support it in the future.

Thanks,
Priyavadan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Origen is supported on Windows, but at present most of the user base is on Linux.

There is a [Windows installation guide here](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/installwin/), though it has a tendency to go out of date due to it being used less often than its Linux counterpart.

Please raise a ticket on Github if you end up here because of it not working: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/issues